# Find the sum of the following convergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Through the partial sums, find the value of convergence of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n+5}{(n^2-1)(n+2)} $$

I've used $ \frac{A}{(n+1)(n-1)} + \frac{B}{n+2}$ but I get lost when I do the system of equations because B still has k.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First, use the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to prove that the original series converges. Then, use the fact that
$$
\frac{n+5}{\left(n^{2}-1\right)\left(n+2\right)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I did found that it converges but I can't figure out how to get to $\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{2}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+2}$

Comment: $\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{2}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}=\left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right).$

Answer (score 1):

You've already broken it down into two fractions. Now further break your first fraction into two more fractions to arrive at the three fractions @parsiad already gave you. The rest you should be able to do. Good luck!